# JOIN to change string in column cells

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query that gets 2 columns from different tables based on JOIN associations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT co.item_name
    ,SUBSTRING((
            SELECT ',' + ca.attr_val AS [text()]
            FROM [CONTRACT_ATTR] CA
            WHERE CA.Item_Id = CO.Item_Id
                AND ca.field_id = 239
            ORDER BY co.item_name
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 2, 1000) GM_PROG
FROM [dbo].[CONTRACT] CO;
```

[image]

The 2nd column has numbers and those numbers are keys on a lookup table.

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to change the numbers into the correct item_name.

I believe it has to do with the query inside the substring:

```
        SELECT ','+ca.attr_val   AS [text()]
        FROM [CONTRACT_ATTR] ca
        JOIN GM_PROGRAM gm
        ON ta.GM_PROG = gm.item_id
        WHERE CA.Item_Id = CO.Item_Id
            AND ca.field_id = 239
        ORDER BY co.item_name
        FOR XML PATH ('') ta
    ), 2, 1000) GM_PROG
```

This is where I'm at. I doesn't run and I think this is because its trying to reference.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, you just need to change `ca.attr_val` to `gm.item_name`, your join referenced `ta` instead of `ca` (typo I would guess), and probably sort on `gm.item_name` instead of `co.item_name` in the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT co.item_name
    ,SUBSTRING((
            SELECT ',' + gm.item_name AS [text()]
            FROM [CONTRACT_ATTR] CA
            inner join GM_PROGRAM gm
              ON ca.attr_val = gm.item_id
            WHERE CA.Item_Id = CO.Item_Id
                AND ca.field_id = 239
            ORDER BY gm.item_name
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 2, 1000) GM_PROG
FROM [dbo].[CONTRACT] CO;
```

Comment: I am getting this. Invalid column name 'GM_PROG'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "ga.item_name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
The multi-part identifier "ga.item_name" could not be bound.

Comment: @DavidTunnell My bad, that should have been `gm.` instead of `ga.` I misread the alias. -- updated my answer to correct it

Comment: No problemo. I really appreciate the help. With the update it looks like only the 1st issue now: Invalid column name 'GM_PROG'. Maybe because its created and isn't a 'real' column?

Comment: @DavidTunnell I was pulling `xx.GM_PROG` from your code in the question. Would it be `ca.attr_val` instead?

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you!